# How to make users posts to appear on a page?

Tags: php, mysqli

I want every time someone posts something that post to appear below the one that already exists. If I use this it only replace the last post.
How should I do it?

```
<?php
session_start();
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "store");
if (isset($_POST['button'])) {
    session_start();
    $title= mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['title']);
    $body= mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['body']);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO content (title,body) VALUES ('$title', '$body')"; 
    mysqli_query($db, $sql);
    $_SESSION["title"] = $title;
    header("location: home.php");
}
?>
```

And on the page that I want to display:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    php echo $_SESSION["title"];
?>
```

Comment: you need to redirect and loop over results on successful query with SELECT. btw, use a prepared statement. Even what you're using could be injected. You also have 2x `session_start();`, remove the 2nd one.

Comment: Question's too broad also. In order to "learn something", you need to "try something". When you've written some code and may be faced with a problem, only then we'd help. Or, you can wait for someone to come along and "drop a fish" on your lap. Learning "how" to fish will indeed pay off bigger rewards; for "you". Restaurants eventually close, so the cook won't always be there for you. Learn how to cook for yourself ;-) that way you won't get stuck and will know what to do.

Comment: @Fred -ii- i will look into redirect and loop i didn't even knew what to search for ...

Comment: `php echo $_SESSION["title"];` should be `echo $_SESSION["title"];`

Comment: The page that you want to display need to query the database for all the information you want it to display. echoing a session variable is not doing anything

Comment: @OneBeginer. I have provided with some suggestions and corrections to the code. Have a look and share thoughts . Let me know back again if you face any hindrance in development...

Comment: @Fred -ii- I changed the code with prepared statments , but i can't make the loop work , can u please explain to me how should i do it or give me an example ? Sorry i dont rly know what i am doing ...

Answer (score 0):

You have to redirect the page to the `home.php` on any condition but you have not done that.

if `mysqli_query()` after execution returns `FALSE` or `TRUE` the header location will be done and that is not advisable. Since you are needing to `echo` the `SESSION variable` over to the `home.php` page.

You can check condition like this if needed.

```
if(mysqli_query($db, $sql))
{
// Here you can handle the TRUE loop
$_SESSION["title"] = $title;
header("location: home.php");
}
else
{
// Here you can handle the FALSE loop
}
```

And in the `home.php` you have make the following modifications in order to display the session variable to print.

> Check Points to print the session variable in other page

1. Ensure that you have `session_start()` at the top of the page since you need to get the super global variable over to that page.
2. If you need to show anything that is queried from the DB you need to ensure the connection of DB over to that page.
3. If any header Location error occurs try to restart your output buffering over to the page where you have started you header location. You can restart your output buffering with the help of `ob_start()`
4. `ob_start()` must be used only if you get `header already sent error` in the redirection problems.

Usage of `ob_start()`:

Thinking of `ob_start()` as saying "Start remembering everything that would normally be outputted, but don't quite do anything with it yet."

Example:

```
ob_start();
echo("Welcome User!"); //would normally get printed to the screen/output to browser
$output = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

`ob_start()` - Turn on output buffering

This function will turn output buffering on. While output buffering is active no output is sent from the script (other than headers), instead the output is stored in an internal buffer.

The contents of this internal buffer may be copied into a string variable using `ob_get_contents()`. To output what is stored in the internal buffer, use ob_end_flush(). Alternatively, `ob_end_clean()` will silently discard the buffer contents.

Returns **TRUE** on success or **FALSE** on failure.

> And over to the question you have made you have to make some changes

You have started the `session` and that is good but you have appended the `php` to the echo statement and that looks incorrect.

**Replace:**

```
php echo $_SESSION["title"];
```

**with:**

```
echo $_SESSION["title"];
```

Rather all the other codes are fine.

And to the whole the Entire page will look like this.

```
<?php
session_start();
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "store");
if (isset($_POST['button'])) {
    //session_start(); This is not needed at all already you have started the session.
    $title= mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['title']);
    $body= mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['body']);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO content (title,body) VALUES ('$title', '$body')"; 
    mysqli_query($db, $sql);
    $_SESSION["title"] = $title;
    header("location: home.php");
}
?>
```

**home.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    echo $_SESSION["title"];
?>
```

> **Note:** Your Code is at SQL Injection vulnerability it is advised to use of the prepared statements along with `mysqli.*`

**Prepared Statements Reference for Mysqli:** - http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php.

I think my explanation would be clear for you to rectify your Error and code pretty good.

Thanks & Happy coding:)

Comment: I rewritten the code with Prepared Statements and it works but i still haven't managed to do the loops i just started with php a few days ago and i dont rly know how to do it.